# Yii booster - renderPartial the data-content of a popover?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, yii, popover, renderpartial

I'm using Yii with YiiBooster extension. I want to have a popover like this:

```
array(
        'header' => '',
        'value' => function($data)
        {
            $this->widget('bootstrap.widgets.TbButton', array(
                'label'=>'Inne',
                'type'=>'primary',
                'size' => 'mini',
                'htmlOptions'=>array(
                    'data-placement'=>'right', 
                    'data-content'=> "Controller::renderPartial('_statButtons', 
                                      array('data' => $data->idProject));", 
                    'rel'=>'popover'
                ),
            ));
        }
    ),
```

This is inside the cell of the gridview. I would like to use `renderPartial` to render a file with some content but above code is not working. How can I achieve it?

EDIT: 
if the code exucutes (my code or the @Ruslans code) it is the result:

```
Here is the text from the _statButtons partial file. End of this file.
<a id="yw2" class="btn btn-primary btn-mini" rel="popover" 
   data-placement="right" data-original-title="" title="">Inne</a>
```

Comment: what error does above code raise?

Comment: There is no error at all. The way above: it just puts the code as it is as text. If I remove the `"` - it is rendered not inside the `data-content` but as a text that is placed before the button.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

bellow code works. I use PHP 5.3

```
'value' => function($data) use($controller)
{
    $controller->widget('bootstrap.widgets.TbButton', array(
        'label'=>'Inne',
        'type'=>'primary',
        'size' => 'mini',
        'htmlOptions'=>array(
            'data-placement'=>'right',
            'data-content'=> $controller->renderPartial('_test',
                      array('data' => $data->title), true),
            'rel'=>'popover'
        ),
    ));
}
```

where `$controller` is just reassignment of `$this` var before `CGridView` widget is rendered.

```
$controller=$this;
```

because in PHP 5.3 closures don't have access to `$this` var

As far as I remember, PHP 5.4 can access `$this`.

Calling `Controller::renderPartial(....` - bad approach, because `renderPartial` is not a static function, but called statically. And it should raise error, unless you turned them off.

Comment: The code executes it's true but my code executes too. The problem is that it doesn't put it into the `data-content` option but it is rendered before the button. I added resulting HTML of your code in my question.

Comment: @Joe: in your case two params are passed into `renderPartial`,
in my case there is third param equals to `true`, which says that view content has to be returned, not outputed directly
http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CController#renderPartial-detail

Comment: Oh, my bad - I haven't noticed that. Thank you very much!

Comment: Just a little question at the end - what should I do to put a link into the popover? I tried to use `'data-html' => true` inside the `htmlOptions` but it doesn't work.

Comment: @Joe: the only solution I know is to run `popover` manually, http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/bootstrap/#c11590